# Discord.net sending direct message(PM) to specified user

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I'm new here so don't judge me,
I want to create a command !poke  which sends a direct message(PM) to specified user, but I can't seem to find a way to feed userid to it and documentation is pretty much non existing for discord.net.

```
        commands.CreateCommand("poke")
            .Parameter("target")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                ulong userID = e.User.Id;
                Console.WriteLine("[" + e.Server.Name + "]" + e.User.Name + " just poked " + e.GetArg("target"));
                await e.User.SendMessage("HEY, wake up! ");
            });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this, first is creating private channel with command:

```
                var c = discord.CreatePrivateChannel(ulong userid);
```

and sending message from it like this:

```
                await c.SendMessage("blabla");
```

and another way is storing user as object and then sending message from it.

```
                User u = null;
                string findUser = e.GetArg("target");

                        u = e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault(); //checking mentioned users
                        u = e.Server.FindUsers(findUser).FirstOrDefault(); //looking for specified user in server

                await u.SendMessage("HEY, wake up! ");
```

My command looks like this:

```
        commands.CreateCommand("poke")
            .Parameter("target", ParameterType.Required)
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                ulong id;
                User u = null;
                string findUser = e.Args[0];

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(findUser))
                {
                    if (e.Message.MentionedUsers.Count() == 1)
                        u = e.Message.MentionedUsers.FirstOrDefault();
                    else if (e.Server.FindUsers(findUser).Any())
                        u = e.Server.FindUsers(findUser).FirstOrDefault();
                    else if (ulong.TryParse(findUser, out id))
                        u = e.Server.GetUser(id);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("[" + e.Server.Name + "]" + e.User.Name + " just poked " + u);
                await u.SendMessage("HEY, wake up! ");
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

I think i'm late but I hope this can help. This worked for my bot.

```
[Command("Test")]
            public async Task Test(string message)
            {
                if (message== "Send me a message")
                {

                    await Context.User.SendMessageAsync("Here is your DM message! ;)");
                }else
                {
                    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("I can't send you a message");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Note for this that `SendMessageAsync()` is an extension method (from `Discord.UserExtensions` in another answer), so you need a `using Discord;` to access them as in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
var u = Context.Message.Author;  // Or some other means of getting user_id
string msg = "your message";
await Discord.UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync(u, msg);
```