# Is there a way to send a message for user that not on server?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have a code that sends a message to a user when they are leaving the server, but one problem, bot can send message to a user only if they are on an any server with bot, but when it tries to send message, user already left, and it just cant.

```
public async Task OnUserLeft(SocketGuild guild, SocketUser user)
    {
        await user.CreateDMChannelAsync();
            await user.SendMessageAsync(
            "You left the server");
    }
```

is there a way to send message without being on the server with user? my bot is just for only one server so when user leaves there is no way for bot to share any server with user

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942006/discord-net-sending-direct-messagepm-to-specified-user

Comment: No there isn't a way to message someone that does not share a server with the bot. I also don't see why the person would want to be randomly DMd that they've left a server.